# Why does my character only rotate to the target one time every time it doesn't move?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question might sound confusing but I want to make my code so when my character doesn't move, he looks directly towards the closest enemy. The problem is that when I stop moving my character, it only does the command once and doesn't redirect to the enemy's new position. I tested out many things like making it so when i move, it looks at the enemy and it seems to work but whenever I set it to not move, it doesn't work.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace work.working.worked
{
    public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed;
        public float rotationSpeed;
        public static bool ismoving;
        public Rigidbody2D rb;
        Vector2 movement;
        // Update is called once per frame
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
        void Update()
        {
            movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            if (Input.anyKey)
            {
                ismoving = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ismoving = false;
            }
            if (ismoving == true)
            {
                Vector2 direction = new Vector2(movement.x, movement.y);
                direction.Normalize();
                if (direction != Vector2.zero)
                {
                    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, direction);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
            if (ismoving == false)
            {
                Vector3 direction = FindClosest.closestEnemy.position - transform.position;
                direction.Normalize();
                float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 85f;
                rb.rotation = angle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Input.anyKey you could check that the magnitude of movement vector to see if character is moving.

```cs
ismoving = movement.magnitude > 0.0f;
```

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace work.working.worked
{
    public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed;
        public float rotationSpeed;
        public bool ismoving;
        public Rigidbody2D rb;
        Vector2 movement;
        

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        void Update()
        {
            movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            ismoving = movement.magnitude > 0.0f;

            if (ismoving)
            {
                Vector2 direction = new Vector2(movement.x, movement.y);
                direction.Normalize();
                if (direction != Vector2.zero)
                {
                    Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, direction);
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Vector3 direction = FindClosest.closestEnemy.position - transform.position;
                direction.Normalize();
                float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 85f;
                rb.rotation = angle;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Also don't make `ismoving` variable static** or it gets set by every active Movement component in loaded scenes which can lead to unexpected behavior down the line. If its public, you can see it's state in Unity inspector by selecting the GameObject with Movement component.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I'm new to Unity and i don't really get what to replace with ismoving = movement.magnitude > 0.0f;

Comment: @Gntionofl from what I understand is relying on the engine to determine if the object is being moved. In Phyisics magnitude is used use to measure, in this case of the speed vector.

Comment: My answer is using input vector that is set each frame by Input.GetAxisRaw for both x and y axis right before is moving check. It has nothing to do with physics.

Comment: If no movement key is pressed the magnitude of the movment vector will be zero and since Rigidbody2D.MovePosition is used the character will stop instantly since `movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime` will return zero vector.

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn't work. When my character stops moving, it only looks at the enemy once and when the enemy moves into a new position, my character doesn't readjust to its new position. Basically meaning that it only turns once.